# ¿Como evaluar en un condicional si se realizó click en algún elemento? (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día. Mi duda es saber de qué forma puedo evaluar en un condicional si se clickeó en un elemento. Algo parecido a evaluar si un checkbox fue seleccionado, pero en este caso es un elemento cualquiera.

Se me ocurre algo como:

```
if($('input[data-name=sms]').on('click')){
    alert('Se hizo click en sms');
}
elseif($('input[data-name=audio]').on('click')){
    alert('Se hizo click en audio');
}
elseif($('input[data-name=email]').on('click')){
    alert('Se hizo click en email');
}
```

Pero no se de qué otra forma puedo detectar esos click que necesito. **Por cierto,** tengo tres posibles elementos, y la idea es hacer algo si se clickeó en uno u otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo con *JQuery* para poder identificar a que elemento se le dió click

**Paso 1**

Tenemos una serie de 3 divs, dentro de un div principal

```
<div id="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

**Paso 2**

Creamos un script que se ejecutará cuando el document esté listo

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#container div").click(function(){
      console.log("Se dio en el valor: "+$(this).text())
    })
})
```

*EXLICACIÓN*

- Por medio de `$` accedemos al contenedor principal por medio de su id, por eso el uso del símbolo `#`
- Ahí mismo indicamos que acceda a los elementos `div`
- Por cada elemento `div` que encuentre dentro del `container` va a disparar el evento `click`
- Ahora para poder acceder al valor que tiene cada div y mostrar a cual se le dió click hacemos lo siguiente `$(this).text()` de modo que se imprima el texto que cada elemento div posee

**EJERCICIO COMPLETO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="container">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <span id="aviso"></span>
      </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          let aviso = $("#aviso")
          $("#container div").click(function(){
          //console.log("Se dio en el valor: "+$(this).text())
          aviso.html("click en el elemento con valor: "+$(this).text())
        })
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. Me acabas de dar una excelente idea, utilizaré la forma como detectas los clic, y más bien en los condicionales valido no por el evento 'click' asociado, pero si evaluaré por el .text() que devolvió el evento.

Answer (score 1):

**Lo resolví de esta manera:**, siguiendo la orientación de @element quién posteó la primera respueta:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".card-content").find('.jsValueChecked').click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'mail'){
     alert("Se dio en el valor: "+$(this).val())
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'audio'){
     alert("Se dio en el valor: "+$(this).val())
    }
    else if($(this).val() == 'sms'){
     alert("Se dio en el valor: "+$(this).val())
    }
    })
})
```

```css
/*Color del radio-button para el 'email'*/
        [type="radio"].with-gap.mailOption:checked+label:after {
            background-color: #00BFA5 !important;
        }
        [type="radio"].with-gap.mailOption:checked+label:before,
        [type="radio"].with-gap.mailOption:checked+label:after {
            border: 2px solid #00BFA5 !important;
        }
        /*Color del radio-button para el 'audio'*/
        [type="radio"].with-gap.audioOption:checked+label:after {
            background-color: #FC0F3A !important;
        }
        [type="radio"].with-gap.audioOption:checked+label:before,
        [type="radio"].with-gap.audioOption:checked+label:after {
            border: 2px solid #FC0F3A !important;
        }
        /*Color del radio-button para el 'sms'*/
        [type="radio"].with-gap.smsOption:checked+label:after {
            background-color: #F8CD30 !important;
        }
        [type="radio"].with-gap.smsOption:checked+label:before,
        [type="radio"].with-gap.smsOption:checked+label:after {
            border: 2px solid #F8CD30 !important;
        }
```

```html
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="card-content" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0;">
 <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 0">
  <div class="col s12">
   <p>
    <input class="with-gap mailOption jsValueChecked" type="radio" checked value="mail" id="email" name="radio" data-name="radio-mail">
    <label for="email">Mail</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input class="with-gap audioOption jsValueChecked" type="radio" value="audio" id="llamada" name="radio" data-name="radio-audio">
    <label for="llamada">Audio</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input class="with-gap smsOption jsValueChecked" type="radio" value="sms" id="sms" name="radio" data-name="radio-sms">
    <label for="sms" style="text-transform: capitalize">Sms</label>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```